# How to protect user access form without login

Tags: php, authentication

I have this script which direct user to Login form if he/she is not loged,But the problem is, when I login and refresh the page it take me back to Login page and also when I login and try to copy the link and paste also it take me back to Login page, instead it suppose to be after logout.

Here the Login script

```
 <?php

   session_start();

   // Connect to server and select databse.
   $link=mysql_connect("localhost","root", "mcl")or die("cannot connect");
   mysql_select_db("mcl",$link)or die("cannot select DB");
   // username and password sent from form
   $fname=$_POST['fname'];
   $password=$_POST['password'];
   $sql="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE fname=('$_POST[fname]') and
   password=('$_POST[password]')";
   $result=mysql_query($sql);
   // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
   $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
   // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
   if($count>0){
       $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['fname'];
       switch($_POST['fname']) {
            case 'root': header("Location: dashboard.php"); break;
            case 'accountant': header("Location: dash_accou.php"); break;
            case 'secretary': header("Location: dash_secretary.php"); break;
            }
              exit;
          }
      else {
        echo "<a href=index.php>Invald username or password <input name=Click here to reload   
         type=button disabled value= <<<Reload></a>";
   }
    ?>
```

Here the script which direct user to login form

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) ||  $_SESSION['username'] != 'root') {
        header('Location: index.php');
       exit;

        }
              ?>

   <?php
   unset($_SESSION['username']);
  ?>
```

Any help, thank u

Comment: You have `session_start();` at the top of ALL pages don't you?

Comment: why r u checking user != root??

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) ||  $_SESSION['username'] != 'root') {
```

Notice your second clause.. this basically means that if the username is NOT root it will redirect him to the login page anyway, so say if user "Jack" logged in.. he will still be redirected to the login page since his username is not "root"

Also, please do note that that **mysql_*** functions are deprecated and instead, you should use [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo). You should also make sure that you validate and sanitize your inputs from attacks by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This is all very important in keeping your website secure.

Comment: I this the reason after refreshing the page to direct user to Login form?